# Как убрать лимит в 300 опций на Opencart?

Tags: opencart

После 300 опций ( разные размеры) выводится ошибка при вводе.

Где это ограничение можно снять?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 15000
```

Или в php.ini, если доступ есть:

```
max_input_vars = 15000;
```

Или может в панели настройкой хостинга есть такие пункты, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо. ЛОгично , но добавил и не помогло . Ищу дальше

Comment: А какая ошибка появляется? В самом Opencart точно нет ограничения на количество опций и атрибутов.

Comment: После 300 введенных в разделе опции величин ( у меня размеры и их очень много так как  продается на вес)  при введении 301 выдает ошибку Undefined index: option_value_description in /home/k/kbuzukrq/wesellyarn.ru/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/option.php on line 438.

До 300 все отлично было

Comment: В option.php  ни в строке 438 ни рядом никаких указаний на количество показателей или других цифр нет

Comment: Строки 430 - 455

Comment: if (isset($this->request->post['option_value'])) {
   foreach ($this->request->post['option_value'] as $option_value_id => $option_value) {
    foreach ($option_value['option_value_description'] as $language_id => $option_value_description) {
     if ((utf8_strlen($option_value_description['name']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($option_value_description['name']) > 128)) {
      $this->error['option_value'][$option_value_id][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_option_value'); 
     }     
    }
   } 
  }

  if (!$this->error) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;

Comment: 100% проблема в `max_input_vars` проверяйте, какое значение сейчас установлено. Попробуйте увеличить значение через php.ini, который лежит в папке admin.

Comment: Сработало увеличение max_input_vars с запасом - взял побольше раза в 2 . Спасибо